# Get current height of div while looping through object in angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I want to generate a view looking like the one when viewing a PDF on google docs with data generated from a database. That is, I want to fill a div the size of an A4 paper, and when it's full, it should continue in a new A4 div. I'm having trouble figuring out the best solution for doing this, so any tip on a possible solution is welcome. My solution so far is as follows:

The HTML below represents an A4 sheet, with the .page as the A4 class.

```
<div class="page">
    <div id="prev">

    <div ng-repeat="week in home.elements" style="width: 100%;padding: 1rem;">
        <div class="week-container" style="background: #fbfbfb;">
            <h5 id="ch1" class="week">{{week.week}}</h5>

            <div class="week-event" print-avoid-break ng-repeat="event in week.events">
                <div class="event-name">
                    <div class="event-color" style="background: {{event.activityTypeColor}}"></div>
                    <h6>{{event.name}}</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9">

                        <div class="event-description">
                            <p>{{event.description}}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">

                        <div ng-if="event.files.length > 0" class="event-files">
                            <p>
                                <span style="float: left;" ng-if="event.files.length > 0">Eventet har filer</span>
                                <span ng-if="event.links.length > 0"> Eventet har länkar</span>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

The controller then have this function which I intended to use to check the height of the div as the div grew when data was loaded in to it. However the div remains at a height of 0 throughout the loop.

```
vm.testingTesting = function(){
    var log = [];
    var myElement = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#prev' ) );

    angular.forEach(vm.wheelTemp.events, function(value, key) {
        myElement = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#prev' ) );
        if (myElement[0].clientHeight < 969) {
            vm.elements.push(value);
        }
    }, log);
}
```

A fiddle to hopefully show what I'm trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/adao9bw5/1/

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app = angular.module('demo', []);

app.controller('homeCtrl', function($scope) {
  console.log("sickValFAm")
  var log = [];
  var myElement = angular.element(document.querySelector('#prev'));
  $scope.elements = [];


  $scope.test = function() {
  console.log(myElement[0].clientHeight);

    angular.forEach($scope.wheelTemp.events, function(value, key) {
      myElement = angular.element(document.querySelector('#prev'));
      if (myElement[0].clientHeight < 969) {
        $scope.elements.push(value);
        console.log($scope.elements);
        console.log(myElement[0].clientHeight);
      }
    }, log);
  }

  $scope.wheelTemp = {
    "name": "ACCRUEX",
    "printDate": "2016-04-09T06:39:40 -02:00",
    "printerName": "Simpson Grant",
    "wheelYear": 2016,
    "events": [{
      "week": 40,
      "events": [{
        "name": "DATAGENE",
        "description": "Esse in culpa sunt Lorem. Eiusmod nostrud incididunt minim mollit occaecat irure ad in non nisi. Aute enim consectetur anim eiusmod consequat Lorem officia exercitation excepteur. Cupidatat qui proident irure occaecat duis.\r\n",
        "activityType": "Gilbert",
        "activityTypeColor": "green",
        "files": [{
          "name": "ipsum"
        }, {
          "name": "dolore"
        }, {
          "name": "eiusmod"
        }],
        "links": [{
          "name": "qui"
        }, {
          "name": "nostrud"
        }, {
          "name": "cillum"
        }]
      }, {
        "name": "APEXIA",
        "description": "Cillum quis incididunt officia fugiat nostrud incididunt est et quis pariatur reprehenderit qui. Laborum anim reprehenderit esse excepteur dolore sint deserunt est amet do ea ad. Quis duis amet eu irure est id.\r\n",
        "activityType": "Cathryn",
        "activityTypeColor": "brown",
        "files": [{
          "name": "eiusmod"
        }],
        "links": [{
          "name": "officia"
        }]
      }, {
        "name": "GEEKWAGON",
        "description": "Excepteur reprehenderit ad mollit dolore cupidatat reprehenderit excepteur sint quis excepteur reprehenderit. Adipisicing mollit cupidatat adipisicing proident voluptate reprehenderit eiusmod ex ea elit voluptate sit culpa qui. Aute incididunt laboris ipsum ipsum.\r\n",
        "activityType": "Ward",
        "activityTypeColor": "blue",
        "files": [{
          "name": "exercitation"
        }],
        "links": [{
          "name": "ipsum"
        }, {
          "name": "culpa"
        }, {
          "name": "ut"
        }]
      }, {
        "name": "EGYPTO",
        "description": "Voluptate nulla laboris nostrud ullamco tempor incididunt qui. Consectetur in eu eu sint nulla sunt culpa. Eu non quis in enim fugiat. Eu elit nisi culpa aute amet reprehenderit aliqua voluptate aliqua quis. Veniam cillum officia est ut voluptate veniam. Sunt minim ullamco deserunt officia duis dolor cupidatat aliquip incididunt excepteur tempor. Mollit non adipisicing veniam aliquip aliqua Lorem anim sint minim sit.\r\n",
        "activityType": "Schultz",
        "activityTypeColor": "green",
        "files": [{
          "name": "minim"
        }, {
          "name": "labore"
        }, {
          "name": "ullamco"
        }, {
          "name": "est"
        }],
        "links": [{
          "name": "veniam"
        }]
      }, {
        "name": "ENQUILITY",
        "description": "Amet adipisicing nisi consectetur occaecat do sint laboris aute officia veniam ullamco proident dolor. Et voluptate nostrud sint ea ut est irure. Occaecat est amet cillum velit amet velit est est ad tempor ipsum est ex adipisicing.\r\n",
        "activityType": "Sykes",
        "activityTypeColor": "brown",
        "files": [],
        "links": [{
          "name": "cupidatat"
        }, {
          "name": "non"
        }]
      }]
    }, {
      "week": 25,
      "events": [{
        "name": "AMRIL",
        "description": "Duis cillum est esse ipsum commodo Lorem. Et sint ad adipisicing sunt ipsum anim. Cillum nostrud voluptate laborum adipisicing mollit eu eu Lorem ullamco.\r\n",
        "activityType": "Vilma",
        "activityTypeColor": "brown",
        "files": [{
          "name": "enim"
        }, {
          "name": "esse"
        }, {
          "name": "aliquip"
        }, {
          "name": "qui"
        }],
        "links": []
      }, {
        "name": "GINK",
        "description": "Dolore sunt aliqua nisi in ut magna irure reprehenderit minim officia magna. Ipsum aliqua non magna adipisicing commodo elit anim labore commodo eiusmod. Dolore labore nostrud ullamco Lorem non sint velit incididunt id incididunt eu irure velit. Esse fugiat reprehenderit ut veniam et qui reprehenderit ut tempor aliquip ut labore id cupidatat. Id nisi qui voluptate in eiusmod Lorem duis quis exercitation laborum quis quis.\r\n",
        "activityType": "Kirk",
        "activityTypeColor": "brown",
        "files": [{
          "name": "officia"
        }, {
          "name": "commodo"
        }],
        "links": [{
          "name": "ipsum"
        }, {
          "name": "sit"
        }]
      }, {
        "name": "GRAINSPOT",
        "description": "Labore consectetur cupidatat ipsum dolor. Dolore qui proident velit ullamco consectetur irure enim cupidatat officia Lorem. Aliqua sint incididunt aliquip aute. Consequat in fugiat non mollit ex sunt. Fugiat labore ipsum ad nisi consectetur enim et esse et ullamco.\r\n",
        "activityType": "Deidre",
        "activityTypeColor": "blue",
        "files": [{
          "name": "ad"
        }, {
          "name": "nostrud"
        }, {
          "name": "ullamco"
        }, {
          "name": "deserunt"
        }],
        "links": [{
          "name": "voluptate"
        }, {
          "name": "proident"
        }, {
          "name": "do"
        }]
      }]
    }, {
      "week": 25,
      "events": [{
        "name": "INCUBUS",
        "description": "Non sit eu eu laborum ex ad laborum. Nisi est nostrud magna do qui cupidatat reprehenderit ad fugiat labore non cupidatat. Exercitation aliqua aliquip in ut velit consectetur nisi velit ex sint dolore et quis.\r\n",
        "activityType": "Castro",
        "activityTypeColor": "brown",
        "files": [{
          "name": "veniam"
        }, {
          "name": "aliqua"
        }, {
          "name": "commodo"
        }, {
          "name": "culpa"
        }],
        "links": [{
          "name": "cupidatat"
        }, {
          "name": "excepteur"
        }, {
          "name": "ullamco"
        }, {
          "name": "nulla"
        }]
      }, {
        "name": "DATAGEN",
        "description": "Fugiat amet excepteur voluptate ut voluptate irure dolor. In deserunt velit do labore dolor cupidatat eiusmod aliqua officia. Occaecat incididunt mollit consequat laboris dolore cupidatat cupidatat nostrud. Dolor laborum laborum veniam officia ut minim ut ex nulla cillum Lorem sint reprehenderit. Magna mollit amet et ipsum. Commodo est elit in exercitation. Cillum non consectetur elit amet nostrud laboris.\r\n",
        "activityType": "Rosie",
        "activityTypeColor": "green",
        "files": [{
          "name": "tempor"
        }, {
          "name": "dolor"
        }, {
          "name": "veniam"
        }, {
          "name": "aliqua"
        }],
        "links": [{
          "name": "mollit"
        }, {
          "name": "enim"
        }, {
          "name": "labore"
        }, {
          "name": "id"
        }]
      }]
    }]
  }
})
```

```css
.print-menu {
  position: fixed;
  padding: 20px;
  right: 350px;
  background: #fff;
  width: 200px;
}

.weeks-to-print-menu {
  max-height: 500px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.weeks-to-print-menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

#wheel-name {
  text-align: center;
}

.wheel {
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: 10%;
}

.wheel img {
  width: 100%;
}

.week-container {
  padding: 2rem;
  border: 1px solid #c9c9c9;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.event-name h6 {
  line-height: 22px;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.week {
  text-align: center;
}

.week-event {
  background: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.event-color {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.week-event p {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.page {
  width: 210mm;
  min-height: 297mm;
  max-height: 297mm;
  padding: 20mm;
  margin: 10mm auto;
  border: 1px #D3D3D3 solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.subpage {
  padding: 1cm;
  border: 5px red solid;
  height: 257mm;
  outline: 2cm #FFEAEA solid;
}

@page {
  size: A4;
  margin: 0;
}

@media print {
  html,
  body {
    width: 210mm;
    height: 297mm;
  }
  .page {
    margin: 0;
    border: initial;
    border-radius: initial;
    width: initial;
    min-height: initial;
    box-shadow: initial;
    background: initial;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='demo'>
  <div ng-controller="homeCtrl">


    <button ng-click="test()" style="width:100px;height:50px;border:1px solid #c9c9c9;text-align: center; line-height : 50px;">
      test
      <button>



        <div class="page" style="overflow:auto;">
          <div id="prev" >

            <div ng-repeat="week in elements" style="width: 100%;padding: 1rem;">
              <div class="week-container" style="background: #fbfbfb;">
                <h5 id="ch1" class="week">{{week.week}}</h5>

                <div class="week-event" print-avoid-break ng-repeat="event in week.events">
                  <div class="event-name">
                    <div class="event-color" style="background: {{event.activityTypeColor}}"></div>
                    <h6>{{event.name}}</h6>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9">

                      <div class="event-description">
                        <p>{{event.description}}</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">

                      <div ng-if="event.files.length > 0" class="event-files">
                        <p>
                          <span style="float: left;" ng-if="event.files.length > 0">Eventet har filer</span>
                          <span ng-if="event.links.length > 0"> Eventet har länkar</span>
                        </p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>

          </div>
        </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I thank you for your answer, however you seem to have missunderstood what i was attemtimng to accomplish. Being able so scroll in the div doesn't help, since my intention is to mimic a A4 paper. Thus it need to create a new div with ".page" once the first one is filled. The intention is to preview a print!